# GPS icon still shows in Android after removeProximityAlert

Tags: android, gps

Why does the GPS icon still show  up in notification bar when I already remove Proximity Alert

> removeProximityAlert

I gave the same PendingIntent that I gave to AddProximityAlert and Proximity Alert is no longer working but GPS icon isn't gone.

Does that mean device still tries to get my position and drain battery?

Comment: Try to unregister GPS lisntner from the location manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is just change flag of PendingIntent to FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT

Answer (score 0):

Try This to close your icon

```
        locationManagerGPS.removeUpdates(GPSLocationListener);
```

and then Check again